# OpenGL gluPerspective and shader question

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, pyqt6

I am trying to learn OpenGL, and I have copied and pasted a few things from various sources. Things are starting to come together, but not quite. Here's my code that is doing something:

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL import shaders
import numpy as np

from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtOpenGLWidgets import QOpenGLWidget
from OpenGL import GL as gl
from OpenGL import GLU
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo
from OpenGL.GL import shaders

class GLWidget(QOpenGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        QOpenGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)        
        
    def initializeGL(self):
        gl.glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1)    # initialize the screen to blue
        #gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)                  # enable depth testing
        
        VERTEX_SHADER = shaders.compileShader("""#version 120
        void main() {
            gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
        }""", GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        FRAGMENT_SHADER = shaders.compileShader("""#version 120
        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = vec4( 1, 1, 0, 1 );
        }""", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        self.shader = shaders.compileProgram(VERTEX_SHADER,FRAGMENT_SHADER)

        self.vbo = vbo.VBO(
            np.array( [
                [  0, 1, 2 ],
                [ -1,-1, 2 ],
                [  1,-1, 2 ],
                [  2,-1, 2 ],
                [  4,-1, 2 ],
                [  4, 1, 2 ],
                [  2,-1, 2 ],
                [  4, 1, 2 ],
                [  2, 1, 2 ],
            ],'f')
        )

    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        print(width, height)
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        gl.glLoadIdentity()
        aspect = width / float(height)

        #GLU.gluPerspective(90.0, aspect, 0.1, 100.0)
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)
        
    def paintGL(self):
        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)        
        shaders.glUseProgram(self.shader)
        try:
            self.vbo.bind()
            try:
                gl.glPushMatrix()
                glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
                glVertexPointerf(self.vbo)
                gl.glTranslate(-0.3, 0.0, 0.0)
                gl.glScale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
                gl.glRotate(45, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 9)
            finally:
                self.vbo.unbind()
                glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
                gl.glPopMatrix()
        finally:
            shaders.glUseProgram(0)
        
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Hello OpenGL App')
        self.glWidget = GLWidget()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.glWidget)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

When I resize the window, though, it distorts my scene. Pretty sure that I need the `GLU.gluPerspective(90.0, aspect, 0.1, 100.0)` line, but when I uncomment that, my objects go away. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I understand what the `gluPerspective` does, but I am not sure about the `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` in the shader script. Ultimately, I guess it will have to implement the gluPerspective functionality myself in the shader script?

Comment: *"When I resize the window, though, it distorts my scene."* - What gets distorted? Do you mean [Perspective distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_distortion_(photography))?

Comment: The triangles I am drawing elongate when I resize the window instead of keeping a constant aspect ratio. I guess I have it all wrong. Maybe my question should be: What is the best way to work with modern OpenGL and Python, and where can I find good documentation on it?

Comment: The image in my answer is created from your code. I commented in the line `GLU.gluPerspective(90.0, aspect, 0.1, 100.0)` and changed `gl.glTranslate(-0.3, 0.0, 0.0)` to `gl.glTranslate(0.0, 0.0, -3.0)`. There is no distortion and no change of the anspect ratio.

Comment: Of course the objects are scaled with the y-axis, because the 1st argument of `gluPerspective` defines the field of view along the y-axis. So the relative size of the objects in relation to the height of the window remains the same.

Answer (score 3):

The perspective projection matrix defines a [Viewing frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum). This is the volume which is projected on the viewport. The viewing frustum is limited by the near and far plane. The geometry is clipped at the 6 planes of the frustum.

[image]

You need to make sure that the geometry is between the near and far planes. Since the z-axis points against the view, you need to move the geometry along the negative z-axis.

Keep the perspective projection (`GLU.gluPerspective(90.0, aspect, 0.1, 100.0)`) and translate the view e.g.:

```py
gl.glTranslate(0.0, 0.0, -3.0)
gl.glScale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
gl.glRotate(45, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 9)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, perfect, so my stuff was outside the frustum. Thanks! I still got the feeling that I'm mixing old and new OpenGL things. Shouldn't I implement the frustum mechanism in the shader code? Is using glMatrixMode legit in modern OpenGL?

Comment: @zeus300 "Shouldn't I implement the frustum mechanism in the shader code"*. No. Also in "modern" OpenGL the matrices are set on the CPU and passed to the shader ([Uniform variable](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL))). In legacy OpenGL there are built-in uniforms (e.g. `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix`) that can be set with the matrix operations.

Comment: @zeus300 I recommend reading a good tutorial. My favorite one is [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/). See [LearnOpenGL - Camera](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera).

Comment: That does indeed look ike a good tutorial. I am trying to do everything in Python. Does everything I find implemented in C++ there have corresponding Python equivalents? OR do I need other PYthon libs for that? I'm confused by all the libs there are like pygame or moderngl, for example.

Comment: @zeus300 The OpenGL API is implemented by the graphics driver. So you can use OpenGL with C++ as well as with Python. In C++ you need a loader like GLAD or GLEW. In Python you need PyOpenGL. GLAD, GLEW and PyOpenGL simply delegate to the graphics driver.

Comment: @zeus300 Note: OpenGL is not a library or package for a programming language, but an API provided by the graphics driver. The API is specified here [Khronos OpenGL® Registry](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/index_gl.php)